# how to handle Ajax/POST/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, mamp

my directory structure:
[image]

and thats my ajax Function to send my JSON to my PHP:

```
var myJson={"username":"fsa","name":"fs","lastname":"fdsa","password":"aaa"}
request=new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open("POST", "controller/login.php", true)
request.onload = function () {

if (request.status === 200) {
   console.log(request.status)
} else {
    console.log(request.status)
   }
}
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
request.send(myJson)
```

console.log(request.status) returned the Value "200"
so i don´t think i have a falso function?

On my PHP File i will try to get my Json File.

```
$test = $_POST;
var_dump($test);
echo($_POST);
die();
```

and the response is:
array(0) {
}
Array

Comment: You're not sending a standard POST request (which would be in `$_POST`, not `$POST`.) You're sending raw JSON, so will need to handle it accordingly.

Comment: ohh @miken32 thats a TypeE on Stackoverflow, but not in my Code :)

Comment: Ok, same problem remains that you're sending raw JSON. The duplicate explains how to handle it.

Comment: Also, you should always copy/paste your code directly into the question instead of trying to re-write it by hand.  Typos that exist here but not actually in your code and lead to a _lot_ of wasted time.

Comment: okay but still not working!!